# How to recover the BIOS password of Acer aspire 4720 lappy?

Tags: laptop, bios

I have an acer aspire 4720 laptop.It contains phoenix security. So am unable to enter into bios settings due to the unknown password.

How can i get or remove the password?

Comment: I'm googling it, but just to be sure, could you give us the version of bios, if you know it.

Answer (score 2):

For starters (see my comment) try some of these [backdoor passwords for phoenix bios](http://www.topbits.com/reset-bios-password.html). It's a longshot, but cannot hurt.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to enter into BIOS, why not remove the CMOS battery, set the jumper setting to clear and then again replace the CMOS battery and reboot?

Comment: That was my original answer, but I deleted it after I found no actual confirmation that the motherboard has one that can be removed.  Some reports say that the battery is soldered onto the motherboard.  The Acer service manual fails to mention the location of the RTC battery at all and I do not think that it has a jumper for resetting the BIOS password.

Comment: If you short-circuit the right things it will have same effect as removing CMOS battery. But I can't remember what to short-circuit. I did this quite long time when I forgot my bios pass.